# How to properly execute shell script from nodejs

Tags: node.js, bash

I need to execute a bash script from nodejs app. Usually I would do something like this:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.execFile('./test.sh', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
})
```

But I recently ran into a bash script that never terminated when it was executed like that. This is a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_CTYPE=C cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9" | fold -w 8 | head -n 1
```

- `LC_CTYPE=C` - force the `tr` to interpret everything as ascii characters
- `tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9" < /dev/urandom` - read pseudorandom bytes, discard everything except `a-zA-Z0-9`
- `fold -w 8` - wrap output into lines 8 characters long
- `head -n 1` - read the first line (8 characters)

**When executed from terminal it works fine and it terminates immediately:**

```
# ./test.sh 
0J5hsGeh
```

**When executed using the above nodejs script it just hangs:**

```
# node test.js
```

[image: screenshot from htop command]

It seems that the `head -n 1` already terminated but the `cat /dev/urandom` is still running.

Question: **How to execute the script from nodejs so that it does not hang?**

Env:

- OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`
- Nodejs version: `v6.11.2`

Comment: Try to add `exit` command to the end of your bash script

Comment: Set -x in your shebang or run it via bash -x, we'll have a clearer picture of what's happening

Comment: Guys, thanks for suggestions. However, they do not help. `exit` at the end of the script does nothing and in this case it is not even executed because the previous line never terminates. The `-x` does not help either because the script never finishes so the output generated by `-x` is not printed. Anyways, I am not trying to debug the bash script. I am trying to find out why executing it through nodejs makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that NodeJS [ignores SIGPIPE signal](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events). When a subprocess is spawned the SIGPIPE signal is ignored by the spawned subprocess as well.

Because of that the `cat` command does not terminate when the pipe is broken after the `head` terminated after reading the first line. So the `cat` reads data from `/dev/urandom` forever.

It should be [fixed](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13662) in one of the future versions of NodeJS (not sure which though). For now I just use the workaround from [that issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13662).

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
process.on('SIGPIPE', noop); // <----
childProcess.execFile('./test.sh', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
})
process.removeListener('SIGPIPE', noop); // <----
```